# MacBook Pro 16 inch thermal throttling even when temperatures are low

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, performance, cpu, temperature

Sometimes  when I start to use MacBook its cpu speed limit stays at 20% despite the low temperature. I use the app "HOT" to monitor it. Sometimes even when temperature is 60 Celsius cpu speed limit stays at 20%. Only after a reboot it gets to 100%. Or it takes a very very long time.It might be inactivity of half a day or a day. But cannot predict when it will be reset. Is there any reason for this? Or is is it a hardware fault. I have tried clean install of OS. NVRAM SCM ..etc all the resets. But issue stays the same.
I have asked the same question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1651681/macbook-pro-16-inch-thermal-throttling-even-when-temperatures-are-low) as well.
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: The trouble with staring at hundreds of numbers from 'monitoring' apps is that they give you things to worry about, which may be perfectly normal. Do you see any observable performance reduction in your use of the computer? What is this "Speed Limit" parameter actually measuring? Could the problem be a software fault of the monitoring app?

Comment: Of course there is a performance issue. System is laggy. Why else I would be bothered with the monitoring apps. :-) .

Comment: speed limit means the maximum clock speed cpu can achieve

Comment: But how is it measuring that? What CPU% values are you getting for kernel_task in Activity Monitor? Also what OS version? But really I think this is something you need to take to an Apple Store.

Comment: I added computer details. kernel task is normal ( 5-20%) . HOT application just displays the output of "pmset -g thermlog" command. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/204431/how-to-monitor-and-control-thermal-cpu-throttling-in-os-x
I don't know the internals. But pretty sure machine is throttling despite low temperatures. You suggesting that this can be a hardware fault? I tried reinstalling os. SCM NVRAM all resets there are.

Comment: If you have done a clean install of a new OS, along with SMC and NVRAM resets, then I'd say you've ruled out those things as a cause.

Comment: Can you give us actual performance metrics, like a benachmark?

Comment: Perfomance is laggy. No need to run benchmarks to see it. btw thanks

Comment: I would add the Intel Power Gadget app to get more accurate data on the CPU. https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-power-gadget.html

Comment: It's not unusual for an Intel Mac to run hotter then it probably should. Apple's thinner cases and less effective cooling are a known issue. I force the fans with the Fan Control App (https://crystalidea.com/macs-fan-control/download) This is primarily why Apple is switching to custom Apple Silicon SoC designs.  They are 300% more energy efficient and the M1 chip barely gets hot under normal loads.  Active cooling was added to some models. By the end of 2022 every Mac will have an Apple Silicon CPU. Several more powerful Apple Silicon SoC are expected in the near future.

Comment: Thanks James for the explanation. But I already use intel power gadget , its already in the screen shot. Regarding the issue here it doesn't seem like a temperature issue for reported sensors. Because all the sensors report acceptable values which normally do not lead to throttling. May be there is a temperature issue somewhere else where there are no reported sensors.