# Which CPU temperature should I look at to monitor thermal throttling?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hardware, cpu, temperature

I'm using iStat Menus to display temperature readings from multiple sensors. I want to keep an eye on the CPU temperature to see if the cores are close to their thermal throttling threshold, but there are a lot of temperatures so I am confused.

[image]

Questions:

1. Which "CPU temperature" should I look at?
2. At which temperature threshold would thermal throttling kick in?

Note that I'm not asking whether the CPUs are *currently* under throttling, which has already been answered [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/204431/how-to-monitor-and-control-thermal-cpu-throttling-in-os-x). The point is to monitor the temperature so that I can know if they *will* get throttled and adjust the workload or fan speed accordingly.

Here is the hardware information in case that's relevant.

```
Hardware:

    Hardware Overview:

      Model Name: MacBook Pro
      Model Identifier: MacBookPro14,1
      Processor Name: Intel Core i5
      Processor Speed: 2.3 GHz
      Number of Processors: 1
      Total Number of Cores: 2
      L2 Cache (per Core): 256 KB
      L3 Cache: 4 MB
      Hyper-Threading Technology: Enabled
      Memory: 8 GB
      Boot ROM Version: 429.120.4.0.0
      SMC Version (system): 2.43f7
      Serial Number (system): XXXXXXXXXXXX
      Hardware UUID: XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: They're only a few degrees of each other. (Presumably the Proximity one is a bit further away.) Do they vary more as the temp increases? The CPU is only a 2-core i5, so is it really necessary to manually manage the heat? I would just put iStat menus down and let the OS's built-in heat management handle it.